# Dual task of transitional phrases

Tags: grammar

Can transitional phrases perform the dual task of sentence connector ***and*** adjunct?

1. *He failed to clear the hurdle. In spite of this, he did not give up.*

Here can "in spite of this" be both a connector and an adverb phrase modifying the verb 'give up'?

2. *He is a Vegetarian. Unlike his friend, he doesn't relish eating out.*

Can  "unlike his friend" perform dual function as in the first example. 
Thanks

Comment: Hello, Sanjay. Please be aware that terminologies used in the analysis of sentences may not always correspond and may sometimes conflict. Please give linked and attributed definitions of 'sentence connector' and 'adjunct'.  // That said,  Neither sentence-initial string is needed by the subsequent matrix sentence so most people would consider both to be adjuncts. But only the first seems to connect the sentences semantically to a significant degree. In fact, the second pair of sentences seems a little disjointed. (Why are being a vegetarian and disliking eating out necessarily related?)

Comment: "In spite" takes a PP complement with _of_ +NP. "In spite of this" is an adjunct of concession. "This" is anaphoric to the clause that precedes it. "Unlike his friend" is a PP in a comparative construction.